# How to display array result

Tags: php, html, css

I have a result from the query I made and I stored it in `$entry` (associative array).

It looks like this.

`print_r($entry);`

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [firstname] => John
                [lastname] => Smith
                [quizid] => Qz1
                [easy] => 5
                [normal] => 5
                [hard] => 5
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [firstname] => John
                [lastname] => Smith
                [quizid] => Qz2
                [easy] => 3
                [normal] => 4
                [hard] => 5
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [firstname] => Abe
                [lastname] => Linc
                [quizid] => Qz1
                [easy] => 5
                [normal] => 5
                [hard] => 5
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [firstname] => Abe
                [lastname] => Linc
                [quizid] => Qz2
                [easy] => 3
                [normal] => 4
                [hard] => 5
            )

    )
```

I apologize for the lengthy sample

For now I displayed it like this.

```
Name

John Smith      Qz1 Easy 5      Normal 5        Hard 5 
John Smith      Qz2 Easy 3      Normal 4        Hard 5
Abe Linc        Qz2 Easy 3      Normal 4        Hard 5
Abe Linc        Qz2 Easy 5      Normal 5        Hard 4
```

I used `foreach` in achieving the result above.

```
foreach($entry as $value)
    {
        echo $value['firstname'].'&nbsp;';
        echo $value['lastname'].'&nbsp;';
        echo $value['quizid'].'&nbsp;';
        echo 'Easy '.$value['easy'].'&nbsp;';
        echo 'Normal '.$value['normal'].'&nbsp;';
        echo 'Hard '.$value['hard'].'&nbsp;<br>';
    }
```

But I want to achieve something like this display.

```
Name                Easy        Normal          Hard
                Qz1 Qz2         Qz1 Qz2         Qz1 Qz2
John Smith      5   3           5   4           5   5
Abe Linc        3   5           4   5           5   4
```

I'm having trouble in doing the css on this, I failed in doing so.
How should I do this?

And if there is Qz3, I want it displayed next to Qz2.
Any insight(s) will do!

Comment: Kindly attach existing code. And also, I think it would be better to change the construction of your array. A better approach would be like [this](http://i.imgur.com/eX6E06K.png). By this type of array you can easily build your HTML table and would require less logic (e.g. grouping of users, quizzes, etc).

Comment: This really helped! I will now change the construction of the array.