# Display array results to the user

Tags: php, arrays

I have seen and tried a lot of examples here on display array results to the user but none of them has worked for me.

The closest to what I am looking for, I suppose, is this:

[How to display array result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345246/how-to-display-array-result)

Again, tried it but it doesn't work.

It doesn't work - meaning the page is coming up blank.

When I try varDump(...) and print_r(...), I get results but I can't seem to display the results to the user.

Does anyone know what modifications I need to make to the code below to get to display the results of sourcename, sourceaddress1 and income1?

```
$rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];
if (is_array($rowIDs) || is_object($rowIDs))
{
foreach ($rowIDs as $id) {
 $sourcename1 = $_POST['sourcename1'. $id];
 $sourceaddress1 = $_POST['sourceaddress1'. $id];
 $income1 = $_POST['income1'. $id];
 echo $id;
 echo $sourcename;
 echo $sourceaddress1;
 echo $income1;
}

[rowIDs] => 1
[sourcename1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Jane Doe
    )

[sourceaddress1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123 Main Street
    )

[income1] => Array
    (
        [0] => $89,000.00
    )
```

'//markup,

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>
      <!--reseed attribute IDs in case of gap resulting from deletions -->
     <input type="hidden" name="rowIDs[]" value="{{rowNumber}}" />
<div class="form-group">

    <input type="text" name="sourcename1{{rowNumber}}" id="sourcename1{{rowNumber}}" value="" class="required requiredField" />
    <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
        <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="sourceaddress1{{rowNumber}}" id="sourceaddress1{{rowNumber}}" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" value="" class="required requiredField" />
    <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
        <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" style="width:250px;"  class="form-control" name="income1{{rowNumber}}" id="income1{{rowNumber}}" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['spouseIncome{{rowNumber}}'])) echo $_POST['spouseIncome{{rowNumber}}'];?>" class="required requiredField" />
    <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
        <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <input id="Button{{rowNumber}}" type="button" rel="remove-row" value="Remove" />
</div>
</script>
<div id="addrow">
    <div>
    <!--reseed attribute IDs in case of gap resulting from deletions -->
       <input type="hidden" name="rowIDs[]" value="{{rowNumber}}" />
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sourcename">Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="sourcename1[]" id="sourcename1" value="" class="required requiredField" />
            <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sourceaddress1">Address</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="sourceaddress1[]" id="sourceaddress1" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" value="" class="required requiredField" />
            <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="income1">Income</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="income1[]" id="income1" style="width:250px;"  class="form-control" value="" class="required requiredField" />
            <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
            <?php } ?>
<input type="button" value="Add More" rel="add-row" />
    </div>
</div>
</div><br><br>
```

Comment: Impossible that `$_POST['rowIDs']` is an object. Objects are php internal, `$_POST` holds external data.

Comment: can you share result you get using print_r ?

Comment: That string concatenation in the array keys look out of place. Please try to explain what you are actually trying to do and what data you actually have. We cannot _guess_ that, you see?

Comment: @arkascha, et al,

Thank you guys for your response and sorry for any confusion. We are giving our users the ability to provide input and if necessary, add more rows to provide additional input.

I posted the result of the print_r above.

And we are attempting to grab the results of the array, display to the user and give the user the opportunity to review the results. If correct, then send it. If not, go back and make additional changes. I just can't get the results to display for the user. I posted the result of the print_r above

Comment: You want to access array elements like that: `$_POST['sourcename1][$id]`...

Comment: _And_ it is unclear what the connection is between `$_POST[rowIDs]` and the index `0` we see in the other fields.

Comment: @arkascha, good point again. Please see updated post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['rowids']` is a number, not an array, so `foreach ($_POST['rowids'] as $id)` is wrong. I'm guessing this contains the number of elements in the other input arrays, so it should be:

```
for ($id = 0; $id < $rowIDs; $id++)
```

You also shouldn't have `if (is_array($postIDs) || is_object($postIDs))`, since the code should run when this input is a number.

The other inputs are arrays, so you need to use array indexing to access them, not string concatenation.

```
$sourcename1 = $_POST['sourcename1'][$id];
```

and similar for the other inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

So, I replace `foreach ($rowIDs as $id)` with your version of for(...)?

It is still not clear to me why with all these changes especially the changes from Barmar, I still can't see the result of the array on the screen. Screen is still blank.

Comment: no none at all.

I do have some form fields that are not arrays.

`if(isset($_POST['employeename']))
$employeename = $_POST['employeename'];
echo '<b>Employee Name:</b> '. $employeename`

These do display results to the screen just fine. It is the array that is an issue.

Comment: Did you get rid of the unnecesary `if (is_array($postIDs) || is_object($postIDs))`?

Comment: good question!. I did not know they needed to go. I only got rid of the is_object. Let me get rid of entire IF... and get back to you.

Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: The very first line of my answer said it's not an array, I though it would be obvious. Every time I try to give posters the benefit of the doubt, they prove me wrong.

Comment: BAM!

That did it! Awesome job sir.

Do you mind looking into why these three lines are giving me an error?

`echo "<input type='hidden' name='employeename[]' value='. $sourcename1 . ' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='ttitle[]' value='{$sourceaddress1}' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='income1[]' value='{$income1}' />";
` These are fields I want to pass their values to the next page that submits to the db.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in C:\xampp\htdocs\disclosures\forms\preview.php on line 18

Comment: Which one is line 18?

Comment: The problem is probably on the line before this, maybe a missing `;`. The first line should be `value='$sourcename1'` without the `.`.

Comment: this is the line.

I made the change but still same error:

`echo "<input type='hidden' name='employeename[]' value='$sourcename1 ' />"; `

Also, would love to credit you for solving the initial problem for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Like I said, the problem is probably on the line before it.

Comment: What problem are you having with accepting my answer to credit me?

Comment: I do sir but just a temporary mental lapse. Just a temporary mental lapse that we all go through. I just accepted one a couple of days or so ago.

Notice that neither your no anyone explain to me. LIke I said, for some strange reason I did not notice the checkmark. That doesn't sound like someone who doesn't know how to accept an answer.

Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

sourcename1, sourceaddress1 and income1 are arrays containing one item. For example, `$sourcename[0]` would return `Jane Doe`.

For more information regarding arrays [please read the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).