# Array displaying only one record

Tags: php, arrays

Friends,

I apologize in advance for posting this question again.

I got great help from [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353489/display-array-results-to-the-user/42353884?noredirect=1#comment71861740_42353884%20) in resolving the problem I was having with displaying array results to users.

The error issue was resolved and result was being displayed.

Problem is the array displays one record.

When we insert multiple rows of records, only one record is displayed.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Basically, by default, a user is presented with one row of textboxes.

If user needs to add additional records, the user clicks the Add button to dynamically add an additional row of textboxes,

The code below is from a page called preview.php. It is supposed to capture all records entered in markup page by the user and displays them so user will have the option to review the records and go back to make changes if needed or submit records if everything is ok.

So far as indicated above, it displays only one record regardless of whether the user created one row or multiple rows.

We would like to capture all rows.

Any ideas what I might be missing with code below?

I apologize in advance. I have to show this tomorrow at work and it has occupied my entire weekend.

```
<?php
//echo "DEBUG POST DATA: <pre>".print_r($_POST, 1)."</pre>";
if(isset($_POST['employeename']))
    $employeename = $_POST['employeename'];
if(isset($_POST['ttitle']))
    $ttitle = $_POST['ttitle'];

echo $employeename .'<br>';
echo $ttitle .'<br> <hr width=400 align=left>';

$rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];

for ($id = 0; $id < $rowIDs; $id++){
    $sourcename1 = $_POST['sourcename1'][$id];
    $sourceaddress1 = $_POST['sourceaddress1'][$id];
    $income1 = $_POST['income1'][$id];

    echo $sourcename1 .'<br>';
    echo $sourceaddress1.'<br>';
    echo $income1.'<br>';
}
?>


DEBUG POST DATA: 
Array
(
    [employeename] => Catherine Duffy
    [ttitle] => Sr. Systems Analyst
    [rowIDs] => 1
    [sourcename1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mark 

Zverkov
        )

    [sourceaddress1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Address1
        )

    [income1] => Array
        (
            [0] => $79,000.00
        )

    [sourcename13] => Jim Brown
    [sourceaddress13] => 32 Xooker Rd
    [income13] => $99,000.00
    [spousename] => 
    [spouseAddress] => 
    [spouseIncome] => 
    [dividentname] => 
    [dividentaddress] => 
    [dividentAmt] => 
    [reimbursmentName] => 
    [reimburseAddr] => 
    [remursementAmt] => 
    [inputHonoraria] => 
    [giftname] => 
    [giftaddress] => 
    [giftamount] => 
    [orgname] => 
    [orgaddresss] => 
    [donationamt] => 
    [creditorname] => 
    [creditoraddress] => 
    [creditAmt] => 
    [email] => 
    [submitted] => true
)
Catherine Duffy
Sr. Systems Analyst

Mark Zverkov
Address1
$79,000.00
```

//Markup

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>
      <!--reseed attribute IDs in case of gap resulting from deletions -->
     <input type="hidden" name="rowIDs[]" value="{{rowNumber}}" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sourcename{{rowNumber}}">Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="sourcename1{{rowNumber}}" id="sourcename1{{rowNumber}}" value="" class="required requiredField" />
        <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
            <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sourceaddress1{{rowNumber}}">Address</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="sourceaddress1{{rowNumber}}" id="sourceaddress1{{rowNumber}}" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" value="" class="required requiredField" />
        <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
            <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="income1{{rowNumber}}">Income</label><br>
        <input type="text" style="width:250px;"  class="form-control" name="income1{{rowNumber}}" id="income1{{rowNumber}}" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['spouseIncome{{rowNumber}}'])) echo $_POST['spouseIncome{{rowNumber}}'];?>" class="required requiredField" />
        <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
            <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <input id="Button{{rowNumber}}" type="button" rel="remove-row" value="Remove" />
</div>
</script>
<div id="addrow">
    <div>
    <!--reseed attribute IDs in case of gap resulting from deletions -->
       <input type="hidden" name="rowIDs[]" value="{{rowNumber}}" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sourcename">Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="sourcename1[]" id="sourcename1" value="" class="required requiredField" />
        <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
            <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sourceaddress1">Address</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="sourceaddress1[]" id="sourceaddress1" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" value="" class="required requiredField" />
        <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
            <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="income1">Income</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="income1[]" id="income1" style="width:250px;"  class="form-control" value="" class="required requiredField" />
        <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
            <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
        <?php } ?>
        <input type="button" value="Add More" rel="add-row" />
    </div>
    </div>
</div><br><br>
```

Comment: It might be useful to see the HTML form so we can check names/occurances

Comment: Are you sure that $_POST contains the data you're expecting?

Comment: what the output of `print_r($_POST);` ?

Comment: Should you be incrementing $_POST['source$id'] ?  Let's see the html form field names?  And the $_POST data.  Maybe it's a problem back at the form naming, but we don't know yet.

Comment: Small Aside: There is nothing wrong with `echo $_POST['sourcename1'][$id];` You dont need to move array data to a scalar variable to echo it

Comment: If we look at [otherquestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353489/display-array-results-to-the-user/42353884?noredirect=1#comment71861740_42353884%20in) we can make an assumtion or 2. **but we all know assumptions are dangerous**

Comment: Looking at your other question, I see no `<form>` I do see a `<input type="button" value="Add More" rel="add-row" />` which would not submit the form if it existed, without some javascript, which I cannot see.

Comment: There is just not enough information in your question to do anything other than **make guesses**

Comment: @RiggsFolly, et al,

Thanks so much for your kindness.

I have updated the code above with markup that you asked for.

Comment: sourceaddress1{{rowNumber}} << your not creating arrays `sourceaddress1[{{rowNumber}}]` square brackets required

Comment: @RiggsFolly,if you want me to post entire code, I will. It is very long and yes, it does have <FORM>...</FORM>

And it is posting. The issue is that the preview.php is  not capturing everything it is posting.

Comment: Can you post what you see when you uncomment the line `echo "DEBUG POST DATA: <pre>".print_r($_POST, 1)."</pre>";`? It doesn't seem like your HTML form is structured the way your PHP is expecting.

Comment: @BrileyHooper, sure please bear with me. My laptop is chosing wrong time to hand on me

Comment: @BrileyHooper, thanks for your patience. I had to shutdown my laptop after it became unresponsive.

I am about to post the the out of print_r.

As you can see Briley, the printer_r shows two rows of records inserted but only one record is being displayed at the bottom.

For those angry and downvoting me and wanting the question close,sorry I could not answer your questions as quickly as you wanted it. Just too many questions coming to me at one.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it is obvious you are the one that downvoted me. Please review your comments and the rest of the comments from other helpers. Your comments have no relevance to the help I am looking for.

I don't mind a downvote please do so within reason.

Comment: Actually that dump shows that the field names in the form are not what you think `sourcename13` will not get found in your loop using `$_POST['sourcename1'][$id];` **ditto the other fields**

Comment: No, you are wrong. The field is called 'sourcename1'and {$id]  is intended to add the number hence this: ` name="sourcename1{{rowNumber}}"`

So, if the current value of {{rowNumber}} is 3, that's what is attaches to sourcename1.

I appreciate that you are looking at my post but please show some decorum. If you don't have an answer to my question, with all due respect, don't try to influence others into downvoting me.

Comment: No you are wrong. Look at `[sourcename1]` it has ONLY ONE OCCURANCE [0] but there are other occurances in the array called `[sourcename13] => Jim Brown` **that member of the array is NOT part of an occurance called `[sourcename1]`**

Comment: nogad is right, the root problem seems to be html form field naming.  There may be other issues, but this is the first one to deal with.  Also, it would be good if you presented the html on this page, in case the other page gets deleted.

Comment: The name attribute should look like `name="sourcename1[]"` on all occurances of the `sourcename1` field in the HTML _ditto the other fields_

Comment: Or possibly `name="sourcename1[{{rowNumber}}]"` but I would not do it that way just stick with the `name="sourcename1[]"`

Comment: I am with RiggsFolly on the field naming.  And why have the 1 in the name value?  is there incrementing going on?

Comment: @mickmackusa, I could have sworn that I posted the HTML. It might have been lost after my laptop got hung up. Yes, I do have sourcename1[].

The 0 RiggsFolly is referring to is the index.

sourcename1, sourceaddress1 and income1 is the first row which means it is on index 0. It is different from sourcename1 with id of 3 making it sourcename13. No, he is wrong.

I have updated code with html.

Comment: But if you do that i.e. call the field `sourcename13` it is fine, **but it will not get picked up in your for loop!!!!!!!**

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am just shaking my head here. It doesn't matter if I call it sourcename1 or just simply sourcename. The id is just intended to append whatever value was assigned when the submit button was clicked. IT DOES NOT MATTER RiggsFolly. If you have something more tangible to offer, I will respond further. Otherwise, let me concentrate on those helping me solve my problem.

Comment: It does if you want to process it in the for loop that you have written

Comment: Can I remind you that your title was **Array displaying only one record**

Comment: I give up, you can lead a horse to water but you cannot make it think!

Comment: @RiggsFolly, just so I am not losing. If I have this on the markup:

`name="sourcename1{{rowNumber}}` and then on my preview.php page, I have this:

` $rowIDs = $_POST['rowIDs'];
 $sourcename1 = $_POST['sourcename1'][$id];`

Please tell me why preview.php cannot display sourcename1 + the value of $id which you wont know until submit button is clicked. What am I missing?

MY issue is somewhere in preview.php that is not done correctly to capture ALL the values come from the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code snippets and debug you posted, your PHP code appears to be expecting the data in a different format than your HTML form is generating. It's clear that you have a lot going on with the form, I might suggest starting a new, blank page and re-creating the form piece by piece to make sure each piece submits correctly before you add the next block of fields.

Specific to the question of receiving multiple records from the form, if you format your HTML for the part of the form that gets repeated (assuming `{{ rowNumber }}` gets replaced by `1`, `2`, `3`,... each time a new one is added) like this:

```
<div class="this-div-gets-repeated">
    <label>
        Source Name:
        <input type="text" name="source[{{ rowNumber }}][name]"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        Source Address:
        <input type="text" name="source[{{ rowNumber }}][address]"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        Income:
        <input type="text" name="source[{{ rowNumber }}][income]"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

They you can expect to parse it in PHP like this:

```
<?php
$sources = isset($_POST['source']) ? $_POST['source'] : []; // just in case no sources are posted
foreach ($_POST['source'] as $id => $source) {
    $sourcename = $source['name'];
    $sourceaddress = $source['address'];
    $income = $source['income'];
    echo "$sourcename<br>$sourceaddress<br>$income<br>";
}
```

*Edit: further comments on your HTML*
Your HTML form has two blocks: a set of fields for the first "record", and then a repeating template for any additional records.
The first issue with your HTML is that your "first record" form fields have different names than your "more records" form fields:
Your "first record" form fields have fields like `<input type="text" name="sourcename1[]"/>`.
Your "more records" form fields have fields like `<input type="text" name="sourcename1{{rowNumber}}"/>`.
If you were to look at the HTML that gets generated once you've clicked "Add More" a couple times, your HTML would look like this:

```
<!-- the default "first record" -->
<input type="text" name="sourcename1[]"/>

<!-- from the first click on "Add More" -->
<input type="text" name="sourcename11"/> 

<!-- from the second click on "Add More" -->
<input type="text" name="sourcename12"/>
```

From that you can see how the values entered into the "first record" fields will appear differently than the values from the dynamically-added "add more" fields?

It also appears that there's some weirdness happening with your Angular templates: your PHP $_POST contains the values from your "first record" fields (in `[sourcename1] => Array`), and there are values from your "add more" fields (in `[sourcename13] => Jim Brown` where `{{rowNumber}}` was `3`), but are you intentionally starting `{{rowNumber}}` at `3` in Angular?

Comment: @This is exactly what I like. You can criticize my code or my approach but you provide constructive advise and in your case, case sample, I appreciate that very much.

Thank you.
I guess my question is what is the difference between your sample code and mine. By the way, I am using AngularJS to create the dynamic bit. I ask so I can understand better.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Angular, but let me update my answer with what issues I see with your HTML (now that you've re-posted it)

Comment: thank you for your patience and even-keeled approach.

Comment: @BrileyHooper I hope you are prepared for the long haul on this one

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I thought you said you gave up. He said he is updating his comment. Once he is done, I am done. It either helps me solve my issue or I go to work tomorrow and tell my manager I need more time.

I will resolve this, you can bet on that.

Comment: If you review my comments tomorrow, calmly in the cold light of day, you will hopefully see what I have been trying to say all along.

Comment: Well in fact I have just reviewed @BrileyHooper comment under his edit and as far as I can see, he is agreeing with everything I have been trying to tell you all along. ___How odd___

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the difference is he is pointing out issues and doing his best to suggest solution. If you were doing that, it would not have bothered me as it is doing now,

Briley, just one more question and I promise to stop. How do you suggest I handle sourcename1[] which as you state is different from the dynamically generated fields?

Do I add {{rowNumber}} to sourcename1 as well?

Comment: @Kenny I'd suggest making your initial block of fields look like `<input name="sourcename[1]"/>`, and then your dynamic fields like `<input name="sourcename[{{rowNumber}}]"/>`. If you do that and make sure to start `rowNumber` at 2, then your PHP $_POST will have all of the info in the same place that you can loop through.

Comment: That being said, and again not being familiar with Angular, I noticed that you have `<input type="hidden" name="rowIDs[]" value="{{rowNumber}}" />` with your non-dynamic set of fields. If that value gets changed every time the "Add More" button gets clicked, then that's also going to throw you off. If you name the non-dynamic field "sourcename[1]", then you should probably change that non-dynamic hidden input to be `value="1"` instead of `value="{{rowNumber}}"`